# good way to handle a bunch of data in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, hashtable

I'm returning a complex result of indeterminate size that I will need to handle again and again, so I'm wondering what is a good way to package it?

something like this

loop>>>

```
@results = { external_id => { :name => name, :type => type } }
```

or

```
@results = [ { :external_id => external_id, :name => name, :type => type } ]
```

or?

end>>>>

and if it ends up being a hash of a hash, do i just use merge?

Thanks

Comment: How will you be using the data?  (1) Will you be iterating over the individual elements?  (2) Will you be looking up arbitrary elements?  (3) Does ordering matter?

Comment: What would you want to be using merge for?

Comment: At the moment it gets put directly in the database, but I want to move it out into a gem, so the gem will now provide a hash which will then get handled and put into sql by other parts of my application.

Comment: merge?  i'm not quite sure how to build the hash in a loop.

Comment: hash_of_hash = {}
data.each do |x|
  hash_of_hash[x[:key]] = {:name => x[:name], :type => x[:type]}
end

you mean like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with an array of a hash... and it works fine.

Comment: Great. Please mark this answer as accepted so your question drops from the unanswered list.